# List generators

Tags: list, dictionary, generator

I'm weak in generating of a list. Please help me how i may to get this structure :

```
cash = [[01110101010, {'01110101010100010000000110010100': 1477317843.506, '01110101010100010000000110010101': 1477317843.906}], 01110101011, {'01110101011100010000000110010100': 1477317843.506, '01110101011100010000000110010101': 1477317843.906}]]
```

example:
for bloch in cash:
block[0][0] is 01110101010 and it is always equal to the first 11 numbers of each key in the appropriate dictionary. Keys add in that case if their first 11 numbers equal to the block[i][0]

from this stricture:

```
cash = [[01110101010, {'01110101010100010000000110010100': 1477317843.506}], [01110101010, {'01110101010100010000000110010101': 1477317843.906}], [01110101011, {'01110101011100010000000110010100': 1477317843.506}], [01110101011 {'01110101011100010000000110010101': 1477317843.906}]]
```

example:
for bloch in cash:
block[0][0] is 01110101010 and it is always equal the first 11 numerous for all keys in the appropriate dictionary.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question and tell which programming language you are using or set the tag appropriately. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using Python (by looking at your data structure) following solution should workd for you

**Note:** I have edited your input to make first element as string because numbers starting with 0 are interpreted as octal and I thought that is not whay you may want

```
cash = [
    ['01110101010',{'01110101010100010000000110010100': 1477317843.506}],
    ['01110101010', {'01110101010100010000000110010101': 1477317843.906}],
    ['01110101011', {'01110101011100010000000110010100': 1477317843.506}],
    ['01110101011', {'01110101011100010000000110010101': 1477317843.906}]
]

op = dict()
for entry in cash:
    key = entry[0]
    value = entry[1]
    op.setdefault(key,{})
    op[key].update(value)
```

**Below op should be okay for you**

```
{
    '01110101011': {'01110101011100010000000110010101': 1477317843.906, '01110101011100010000000110010100': 1477317843.506},
    '01110101010': {'01110101010100010000000110010100': 1477317843.506, '01110101010100010000000110010101': 1477317843.906}
}
```

**But if you insist on list then**

```
op_list = []
for key in op.keys():
    op_list.append([key, op[key]])
```

Will give you following format**

```
[
    ['01110101011', {'01110101011100010000000110010101': 1477317843.906, '01110101011100010000000110010100': 1477317843.506}],
    ['01110101010', {'01110101010100010000000110010100': 1477317843.506, '01110101010100010000000110010101': 1477317843.906}]
]
```